# What do $∞^1$, $∞^2$, or $∞^3$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, lie-groups, transformation, math-history

In studying the history of Lie theory, I have seen the symbols $∞^1$, $∞^2$, and $∞^3$ (cf. Page's excellent [*Ordinary Differential Equations* (1897), *passim*](https://archive.org/stream/ordinarydifferen00pageuoft#page/8/mode/2up/search/oo+)). What exactly do they mean?

Comment: It could be referring to a [transfinite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number) but in those cases we generally would avoid using the symbol $\infty$ and instead use one of the more precise $\aleph_n$, $\omega$ or $\mathfrak{c}$ symbols to specify *which* type of infinity we were using.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: I think that the context is that of [Infinite Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group): in [modern terms](https://books.google.it/books?id=8Aa4uS6ZcJEC&pg=PA3) we have: "Let $\mathbb K$ denote the field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. We denote by $\text {GL}(n,\mathbb K)$ the group of *linear isomorphisms* of $\mathbb K^n$, called the *linear group* of dimension $n$."

Comment: In ["older" terms](https://books.google.it/books?id=wxAyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA30) we have: "Now, if we have a family of $\infty^r$ transformations: $x'_i = f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n, a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ which forms an $r$-term group..."

Comment: It means a 1, 2, or 3-dimensional manifold (in Lie theory, a Lie group).

Comment: It seems that you are using a seriously outdated book for your study of Lie groups.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I'm studying the history of the theory.

Comment: @anon The context is the history of Lie theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\infty^n$ was used in the past to refer to a (typically continuous) family of solutions to a problem parametrized by $n$ parameters. This is what we call an $n$-manifold now.

The classic book [Geometry and the Imagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_and_the_Imagination) used this notation:

[image]

Comment: How does one pronounce $∞^1$, etc.? "1-manifold" etc.?

Comment: @Geremia, exactly.

Comment: What? I imagine people just pronounced it the way it looks: "infinity, infinity squared," etc.